# Work Items Feature Related Across the project

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

Is it possible to create two work items in different project but related each other ?

Description;

i mean Project 1 has a work item "ABC", and Project 2 has work item "ABC"
if I change state of my work item "ABC" from doing to done at Project 1, is it possible to have my work item "ABC" at Project 2 automatically change from doing to done as well?

looking for help

Thank you

Regards
Azh

Comment: Hello, is there any updates for this question? Please check whether my answer can help you and feel free to comment~

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to relate two work items and regardless of automatically change state, you can certainly relate two work items that are in different project. What you need to do is the same as relating two work items in the same project. You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-work-items-support-traceability?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-web-form#cross-organization-work-item-linking) for detailed steps.

As of this time, however, the function of automatically change work items' state is not supported. But Microsoft have added the feature to their roadmap and offered an alternative solution. Please click [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-boards-automate-state-transitions) for details and documentation.

There is a [vote](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365409/automatic-state-transition-based-on-linked-work-it.html) on this function in Developer Community, where you can follow the latest development of this feature.